# Cant open this URL because it is in a php code. Is there another way?

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php if ($usertype=='admin'){
  echo '<br> <input type="button" value="Edit Users" onclick="window.location.href='userlist.php'"><br>';
  } ?>
```

this is ithe code.. Works fine without the url

Comment: Not ask syntax error related question it`s not good way to ask question try to solved by self

Comment: Atleast Syntax should be solved by a developer itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 if ($usertype =='admin' ){
  ?>

 <input type="button" value="Edit Users" onclick="window.location.href='userlist.php'">

 <?php
  } 
?>
```

> **NOTE:** Please Use https://phpcodechecker.com/
>   For **Syntax Check** and  **For check custom common errors**

Comment: @Johnny  Please .Check the right tick if you get the yout ans ;)